# How can I animate each element in my array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uiimage, jquery-animate

hope you all are doing well

I have programmatically button which get the image from array, which have two elements, and this button works with timer

```
func monsterButtons () {

    movingBtn.isHidden = true


    movingBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: randomValueBetween(min: 0, max: 250), y: randomValueBetween(min: 200, max: 500), width: 100, height: 100))
    movingBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    movingBtn.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    movingBtn.setImage(array_monesterImage[randomValueBetween(min: 0, max: imageIndex-1)], for: .normal)
    movingBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(movingBtn)
```

and I'm trying to animation each elements in the array_monesterImage, so I added this code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {


        let chknArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage (named: "chkn1.png")!,
                                   UIImage (named: "chkn2.png")!,
                                   UIImage (named: "chkn3.png")!,
                                   UIImage (named: "chkn4.png")!]

        self.movingBtn.imageView!.animationImages = chknArray
        self.movingBtn.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.movingBtn.imageView!.startAnimating()


        let crzyYelowArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage (named: "crzyYelow1.png")!,
                                        UIImage (named: "crzyYelow1.png")!,
                                        UIImage (named: "crzyYelow1.png")!,
                                        UIImage (named: "crzyYelow1.png")!]

        self.movingBtn.imageView!.animationImages = crzyYelowArray
        self.movingBtn.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.movingBtn.imageView!.startAnimating()
```

but it doesn't work .. is there is another way to animation the elements in array_monesterImage ?

Comment: Why are you adding `UIImageView`  animations in `UIView.animate` block?

Comment: It was trying, but it doesn't work